# Image url shows error while calling to display image in UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have stored the json image url in a array but while calling the url it shows error

Model class

```
import Foundation
  class ProductDetails {
  var productAuthor: String!
  var productPrice: Int!
  var artImages: [ArtImage]!
}

class ArtImage {
  var imagepath: String!
  var imgvideotype: Int!
}
```

TableView Controller Storage variable

```
var globalArr = [ProductDetails]()
```

Parsing function

```
func parseJSONData(data: NSData) -> [ProductDetails] {
    var product_Detail = [ProductDetails]()
    do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

        let jsonProductDetails = jsonResult?["data"] as! [AnyObject]
        //print("the json response is",jsonProductDetails)

        for jsonproductDetail in jsonProductDetails{
            let productDetail = ProductDetails()
           // let jsonProductImageDetails = jsonProductDetails["images"] as! [AnyObject]

            productDetail.productAuthor = jsonproductDetail["first_name"]as! String
            productDetail.productPrice =  jsonproductDetail["prodprice"]as! Int


            // Getting inside the json
            let jsonProductImageDetails = jsonproductDetail["images"] as! [AnyObject]
             var artImagesModelArray  = [ArtImage]()
            for image in jsonProductImageDetails {
                let artImage = ArtImage();
                artImage.imagepath = image["imagepath"] as! String
                artImage.imgvideotype = image["imgvideotype"] as! Int
                artImagesModelArray.append(artImage)
            }
            productDetail.artImages = artImagesModelArray;
            product_Detail.append(productDetail)



            }

        }

    catch {
        print (error)
    }

    return product_Detail
}
```

Tableview DataSource

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserHomeScreenTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.artsAuthorName.text = globalArr[indexPath.row].productAuthor
    cell.priceLabel.text = "\(globalArr[indexPath.row].productPrice)"  
    let productDetailsObject = globalArr[indexPath.row].artImages
    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@",productDetailsObject)


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        if let url = (NSURL(string: self.globalArr[indexPath.row])) {

//The error comes here....in self.global array

            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                        cell.artImageView.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })



    return cell
}
```

Here i have stored the parse json and display some details in tableview cell upto here everything works fine .
 but call async way to load images from array its shows error

any suggestion ..plz..
Thank you

Comment: what kind of error you get?

Comment: what is the error it was showing?

Comment: Cannot subscript a value of type '[ProductDetails]'

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way how you're taking the image url from the ProductDetails.
I guess you need to use something like this:

```
 if let url = NSURL(string: self.globalArr[indexPath.row].artImages[imageIndex].imagepath) { // your code }
```

Because when you perform

```
if let url = (NSURL(string: self.globalArr[indexPath.row]))
```

you get an object of ProductDetails, but not an image url.

Comment: sir the above code will only display one image right, but in my json  response their are lots of image url to display and suggestion..